# How can I access the property of an awaited method in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I have this query, I can't find the correct way to get the price value `(.Amount.GetValueOrDefault())`.

```
private IEnumerable<Product> GetSubsciptionOffers(IEnumerable<StripeProduct> productList)
{
    return productList
        .Select(async product => new Product
        {
            Name = product.Name,
            Id = product.Id,
            Image = new Uri(product.Images.First()),
            Description = product.Description,
            OfferType = OfferTypeEnum.Pro,
            Price = await _planRepo.GetPlanByIdAsync(product.Metadata.First().Value).Amount.GetValueOrDefault()
        });
}
```

The error is:

> Task does not contain a definition for Amount

Comment: How many plan rows are there? A significant number, or just a few (i.e. <5 or so)?

Comment: You should probably *clean up* that code. Instead of selecting data into a new form you are *starting* new tasks and trying to project at the same time. If you need to get amounts by "Metadata" do that *first*, probably in an intermediary `Select` call.

Comment: @spender no more than 10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to parenthesize your `await`:

```
Price = (await _planRepo.GetPlanByIdAsync(product.Metadata.First().Value)).Amount.GetValueOrDefault()
```

The reason is that the `.` operator carries a higher precedence than the `await`.

Comment: This will return an `IEnumerable<Task<Product>>`, not `IEnumerable<Product>`, as per OP's method signature.

Comment: indeed : CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Inovatic.SF.Windows.Payment.Model.Product>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Inovatic.SF.Windows.Payment.Model.Product>'

Comment: @spender: That is correct, but unrelated to the specific error the question is about. The OP will have to change the method signature to `IEnumerable<Task<Product>>` and await the tasks at the call site.

Comment: @spender: Or make the method itself `async`, await the tasks inside the method and return the a newly created enumerable.

Comment: @XavSc: As stated before, this is a different error.

Comment: @XavSc you need to clean up the query. Don't try to do everything in a single query. `asyn` is just syntactic sugar, the method's result will be a `Task<T>`.  This means you'll have to `await` the output of `Select`. Make the service/whatever calls first, *then* try to combine them into results.

Comment: yes I'll play a bit with the return types, lot of fun ahead :o

Comment: This will also issue a new DB request per product item. This literal interpretation of OPs requirements leaves them with a rather poor architecture IMO.

Comment: [Pounding A Nail: Old shoe or glass bottle?](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)

Comment: @spender: SO is not only about answering the question, but also about leaving a reference for other users. They might run into this error in a different context and the answer might be what they are looking for. As far as I am concerned, I am not the architecture police.

Answer (score 2):

So, your approach is going to hit up the database for every product just to fetch its plan, then return a sequence of tasks, for each of which you will have to wait individually. This probably isn't what you want.

Given the small number of plans, it's probably better to fetch these up front, then to join them to the products:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetSubsciptionOffers(IEnumerable<StripeProduct> productList)
{
    //you might need to implement this method
    var plans = await _planRepo.GetAllPlansAsync();
    return productList
        .Join(plans, 
              p => p.Metadata.First().Value, 
              p => p.Id, 
              (product, plan) => (product, plan))
        .Select(x => new Product
        {
            Name = x.product.Name,
            Id = x.product.Id,
            Image = new Uri(x.product.Images.First()),
            Description = x.product.Description,
            OfferType = OfferTypeEnum.Pro,
            Price = x.plan.Amount.GetValueOrDefault()
        });
}
```

and to call this method asynchronously:

```
IEnumerable<Product> prodc = await GetSubsciptionOffers(blah)
```

Comment: can't really mark this as answer but that's probably what I'll try, thanks